# Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.8.7 (Cygwin), Windows 7 64-bit, MySQL 5.5. - MySQL gem fails to install

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7, rubygems, cygwin

I'm trying to install the MySQL Gem for Ruby on Rails on Windows 7 64-bit.  I've installed MySQL Essential 5.1.54 Winx64 from the MySQL website.  I've installed Cygwin, which comes with ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin].  I've installed Rails 3.0.3 from the rails website.  When I do 'gem install mysql', it outputs:

```
Building native extensions.   This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

/usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsnl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

I've downloaded the Instant Rails libmySQL.dll and replaced that in my MySQL directory(C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin).  I have a /etc/my.cnf that points to using 127.0.0.1 as the mysql host.  I can connect to mysql in my cygwin bash shell. I can connect to mysql in a Command Prompt window.  I can start rails using SQLite3 as the database.  I've tried supplying --with-mysql-dir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin to the gem install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try --with-mysql-dir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1,  good luck!